# How can the DataView object reference not be set?

Tags: c#, dataview, datarowview

I have the following sample where the `SourceData` class would represent a DataView resulting from an Sql query:

```
class MainClass
{
    private static SourceData Source;
    private static DataView View;
    private static DataView Destination;
        
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        Source = new SourceData();
        View = new DataView(Source.Table);
        Destination = new DataView();
            
        Source.AddRowData("Table1", 100);
        Source.AddRowData("Table2", 1500);
        Source.AddRowData("Table3", 1300324);
        Source.AddRowData("Table4", 1122494);
        Source.AddRowData("Table5", 132545);

        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Data View Records: {0}", View.Count));         

        foreach(DataRowView drvRow in View)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Source {0} has {1} records.", drvRow["table"], drvRow["records"]));
            DataRowView newRow = Destination.AddNew();
            newRow["table"] = drvRow["table"];
            newRow["records"] = drvRow["records"];
        }
            
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Destination View Records: {0}", Destination.Count));
            
        foreach(DataRowView drvRow in Destination)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Destination {0} has {1} records.", drvRow["table"], drvRow["records"]));
        }

    }
}

class SourceData
{
    public DataTable Table
    {
        get{return dataTable;}
    }
        
    private DataTable dataTable;
    
    public SourceData()
    {
        dataTable = new DataTable("TestTable");
        dataTable.Columns.Add("table", typeof(string));
        dataTable.Columns.Add("records", typeof(int));
    }
        
    public void AddRowData(string tableName, int tableRows)
    {
        dataTable.Rows.Add(tableName, tableRows);
    }
}
```

My output is:

> Data View Records: 5
> Source Table1 has 100 records.
>
> Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object at System.Data.DataView.AddNew () [0x0003e] in /usr/src/packages/BUILD/mono-2.4.2.3
> /mcs/class/System.Data/System.Data/DataView.cs:344 at DataViewTest.MainClass.Main (System.String[] args) [0x000e8] in /home/david/Projects/DataViewTest/SourceData.cs:29

I did some reading here: [DataView:AddNew Method...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.addnew%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)
...and it would appear that I am doing this the right way. How come I am getting the Object reference not set?

Comment: What is your actual goal?  Are you wanting to display the data on a DataGridView?  The DataView is generally used as a DataSource container.  It isn't a GUI object displays Data.

Comment: Keep in mind this is a test to work out an issue with why the dataview wasn't working. In the end, yes, the destination dataview will be displayed in a datagrid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DataView` has to be a view *of something*. The way you've got it, it's not a view of anything (using the default constructor) - you need to at least set the **DataView.Table** property to something.

I think you actually want to create a new `DataTable` for "destination", not a `DataView`.

Comment: +1 - I may indeed create a DataTable instead of a DataView. Not really sure at this point. This was to solve a problem I was facing earlier and the solution was not clearly obvious by anything found on MSDN - especially being basically unfamiliar with DataViews in the first place.

Answer (score -1):

The problem resides in the declaration of the `Destination` dataview. In order for the `AddNew()` to function, there must be an object (in this case, a DataTable) in which to reference and add the new record.

By correcting the following:

```
Destination = new DataView(new SourceData().Table);
```

...the dataview will have it's requirements met. This may not make sense at first - but realize that the `DataView` class isn't really complete until it has a DataTable (or some other form of record set) on which to build.

The output is now:

> Data View Records: 5
>   Source Table1 has 100 records.
>   Source Table2 has 1500 records.
>   Source Table3 has 1300324 records.
>   Source Table4 has 1122494 records.
>   Source Table5 has 132545 records.
>
> Destination View Records: 5
>   Destination Table1 has 100 records.
>   Destination Table2 has 1500 records.
>   Destination Table3 has 1300324 records.
>   Destination Table4 has 1122494 records.
>   Destination Table5 has 132545 records.